# Select records from NOW() -1 Day

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, datestamp

Is there a way in a MySQL statement to order records (through a date stamp) by >= NOW() -1 so all records from the day before today to the future are selected?

Answer (score 429, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation for date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO
WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: how to get now to so on.. mean current date to all records those are available in db. ? this is just for one day but i need all record now to on words. @jon

Comment: Does it consider the user's localtime when the records are in UTC?

Comment: @Adry: I doubt it, but you should test carefully.

Answer (score 83):

Be aware that the result may be slightly different than you expect.

`NOW()` returns a `DATETIME`.

And `INTERVAL` works as named, e.g. `INTERVAL 1 DAY = 24 hours`.

So if your script is cron'd to run at `03:00`, it will miss the `first three hours of records from the 'oldest' day`.

To get the whole day use `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`. This will get back to the beginning of the previous day regardless of when the script is run.

Answer (score 28):

Didn't see any answers correctly using `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB`:

**Subtract 1 day from `NOW()`**

```
...WHERE DATE_FIELD >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**Add 1 day from `NOW()`**

```
...WHERE DATE_FIELD >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Looks "cleaner", somehow, but a bit "heavy" as well.  Is there really any added value in explicitly calling a method rather than using a simple addition/substraction ?

Answer (score 24):

You're almost there: it's `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DateStamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Comment: Confusing using `DATE_ADD` then `-1 day`.

Answer (score 1):

when search field is timestamp and you want find records from 0 hours yesterday and 0 hour today use construction

```
MY_DATE_TIME_FIELD between makedate(year(now()), date_format(now(),'%j')-1) and makedate(year(now()), date_format(now(),'%j'))
```

instead

```
 now() - interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
SELECT * FROM FOO
WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1' DAY