# How Yii2 data provider can return results for last 24h

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, yii2, dataprovider

I need to return results from database table only where updated_at field is not older than 24h.

Inside my index action I have this code:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => SearchStats::find(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

How can I modify this code to return me results that where inserted / updated in the past 24h hours ?

`updated_at` is integer, and I am using `TimestampBehavior`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

SearchStats::find()
    ->where(['>=', 'updated_at', new Expression('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)')])
```

**Related links:**

- [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544438/mysql-now-1-day)
- [Using where with ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail)
- [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html)

Comment: I don't get any results now, and there are records made today o.O

Comment: Could you show how `updated_at` is stored? Example with one value will be enough.

Comment: integer(11) : 1430386702

Comment: If I change `NOW()` to `CURDATE()` it works... I am not sure why

Comment: I updated the question according to your situation. But I think for this kind of data using date formats such as `timestamp` or `datetime` would be a better choice.

Comment: I think that you have syntax error. Well I see that yii2 folks are storing `datetime` as `integer` like I did, I thought that is better way to go. Thanks for help !

Comment: It's just an example, they don't force you to use it. Fixed syntax error. Glad to help.