# MySQL - illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci implicit) and (utf8_general_ci coercible for operation '='

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1267

**When I execute the query below i get this error:**

Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

If you need background behind this code, here is the explanation:
[MySQL - How Can I Automate a View Query That Subtracts Metrics From the Most Recent Date To The Previous Day & Date Stamps The Most Recent Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936232/mysql-how-can-i-automate-a-view-query-that-subtracts-metrics-from-the-most-rec)

I set the 'facebook_insight' table collation to: 'utf8_general_ci,' but I still get the error. Can anyone help me?

**MySQL Query:**

```
CREATE VIEW `facebook_insights` AS  
SELECT  
  t1.id  
, t1.timestamp  
, t1.message  
, t1.posted  
, t1.permalink_url  
, t1.caption  
, t1.link  
, t1.type  
, t1.post_impressions - t2.post_impressions as Impressions  
, t1.post_impressions_organic - t2.post_impressions_organic as Post_Impressions_Organic  
, t1.post_impressions_paid - t2.post_impressions_paid as Post_Impressions_Paid  
, t1.post_engaged_users - t2.post_engaged_users as Post_Engaged_Users  
, t1.post_consumptions - t2.post_consumptions as Post_Consumptions  
, t1.post_negative_feedback - t2.post_negative_feedback as 
Post_Negative_Feedback  
, t1.post_negative_feedback_unique - t2.Post_Negative_Feedback_Unique as 
Post_Negative_Feedback_Unique  
, t1.post_impressions_fan - t2.post_impressions_fan as Post_Impressions_Fan  
, t1.post_impressions_fan_paid - t2.post_impressions_fan_paid as 
Post_Impressions_Fan_Paid  
, t1.post_engaged_fan - t2.Post_Engaged_Fan as Post_Engaged_Fan  
, t1.post_video_complete_views_organic - 
t2.post_video_complete_views_organic as Post_Video_Complete_Views_Organic  
, t1.post_video_complete_views_paid - t2.post_video_complete_views_paid as 
Post_Video_Complete_Views_Paid  
, t1.post_video_views_10s - t2.post_video_views_10s as Post_Video_Views_10s  
, t1.post_video_views_10s_unique - t2.post_video_views_10s_unique as 
Post_Video_Views_10s_Unique  
, t1.post_video_views_organic - t2.post_video_views_organic as 
Post_Video_Views_Organic  
, t1.post_video_views_paid - t2.post_video_views_paid as 
Post_Video_Views_Paid  
, t1.post_video_views_clicked_to_play - t2.post_video_views_clicked_to_play 
as Post_Video_Views_Clicked_to_Play  

FROM  
unpaid_media.facebook_insight t1  
JOIN unpaid_media.facebook_insight t2  
ON t1.id = t2.id   
and t1.timestamp  = t2.timestamp + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: The collation issue isn't with the table. It's with the INTERVAL 1 DAY, you may have to change it's collation. What is the default collation for your DB?

Comment: @SloanThrasher , the default collation for my database is 'latin1 - default collation.'

Answer (score 2):

As I can guess from your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936232/mysql-how-can-i-automate-a-view-query-that-subtracts-metrics-from-the-most-rec), the type of your `timestamp` column is not any of `date, datetime or timestamp`. It's probably `varchar` or `text`.

So when you try to add `INTERVAL 1 DAY` to the value which is not time type you get the error.

You have to convert your `timestamp` column to any of `date, datetime or timestamp` data types.

As a quick fix you can use `STR_TO_DATE()` function in your query:

```
CREATE VIEW `facebook_insights` AS
...
and STR_TO_DATE(t1.timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t2.timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But better alter your table in  order to have correct datatypes.

Comment: thank you! That was it, my 'timestamp' column was a text value. -Ulises