# getting data in database based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using time stamp in this format

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $date= date('F d, Y');
    $time= date('h:i:s A');
```

and it saves the data like this

```
November 5, 2019 12:46:03 AM
```

Now, I want to get and echo the monthly data,weekly and yearly data.

I tried using LIKE '$date%' but I cant get to make it work when it comes to weekly.

in this date's case, I want to get the data from NOVEMBER 5, 2019 and six days prior that(making it a week)
I solved the monthly and yearly by saving it in another column and using that in my where statement, but I dunno how to do that in getting weekly datas

Comment: Sorry, I think this question is still a bit vague.  Could you provide more clarity on what you're looking for?  Where is the data you're working with?  Could this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544438/select-records-from-now-1-day

Comment: In order to do this to this you should use MySQL's built in `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, or `DATETIME` fields.   Storing in `VARCHAR`  makes it extremely difficult.  The format in which you should store this is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`  --  At that point you can use queries like `WHERE my_date_field > 2014` etc etc .. OR `WHERE my_filed BETWEEN` ..  Making for much easier queries ..  Conversely, if you need a human readable format, simply add a field to the DB in `varchar` so you have both MySQL format AND string format.

Comment: Are you using type ```timestamp```? It sounds like you have plain text in your DB, which is not recommendable. Use ```timestamp``` and have a look at ```DAYOFWEEK()```

Comment: @Zak can you please provide code for that, this is basically what my professor taught us so I dont have much to work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be storing dates as strings. Just don't. If you have dates, use the relevant datatype to store them in your database: in MySQL, you want the `datetime` datatype.

In php, you can generate a proper MySQL datetime with format specifier `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`.

With this setup in place, it is easy to apply the filter you are looking for:

```
 mydate >= '2019-11-05' - interval 6 day and mydate <= '2019-11-05'
```

Comment: i saved it in my database in a VARCHAR, then inserted it in database using VALUE(..,'$date $time',...)

Comment: @Remaster: like I said, just don't. Create a `datetime` column instead, use a php expression like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to generate a proper MySQL date, then insert it in your database.

Comment: should i use "mydate" in my statement or the column name of my database table?

Comment: `mydate` stands for the name of your `datetime` column, you can replace it with the real name of that column.

Comment: Welcome @Remaster! Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comments above .. I am answering your request with an example ..

I have created a basic table and insert statement for you to play with ..

```
CREATE TABLE `your_db`.`times` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mysql_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `hr_timestamp` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC));
```

INSERT Some SAMPLE data:

```
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2018-10-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2018-11-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2018-12-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-01-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-02-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-03-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-04-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-04-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-05-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-06-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-07-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`times` (`mysql_timestamp`, `hr_timestamp`) VALUES ('2019-08-07 11:58:46', 'IE Oct 7, 2018');
```

An example of getting data by **YEAR** would be:

```
SELECT * FROM your_db.times WHERE YEAR(mysql_timestamp) = 2018;
```

An example of selecting a specific **MONTH**:

```
SELECT * FROM your_db.times WHERE MONTH(mysql_timestamp) = 04;
```

Example of selecting `BETWEEN` dates:

```
SELECT * FROM your_db.times WHERE mysql_timestamp BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-04-30 00:00:00'
```

You can also use `LT` `EQUAL` and `GT` parameters ..  IE:

```
SELECT * FROM your_db.times WHERE mysql_timestamp > '2018-12-01 00:00:00'

SELECT * FROM your_db.times WHERE mysql_timestamp <= '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: thank you I'll play with that to learn about it more. the other answer solved my problem but I upvoted you. THANK YOUUUU

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the saved datet time stirn to a Date and use that for adding dayss  and comapring

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("November 5, 2019 12:46:03 AM","%M %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p") - INTERVAL 6 DAY;
```

Gives You as Result 2019-10-30 00:46:03

What You have  to do is finally

```
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE("November 5, 2019 12:46:03 AM","%M %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p")  
       < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Comment: I used this sql statment based on what you gave me "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE STR_TO_DATE("November 5, 2019 12:46:03 AM","%M %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p") < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 DAY  "

it returned an error "syntax error, unexpected 'November' (T_STRING)"

Comment: of course this works fine see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6272f173e51d32640ececf0200e062f9